# How to rename all the files in directory

Tags: shell, unix

I have the files like test.log.1, test.log.2, test.log.3 and so on.

I want to append the date at the end of each file and rename it.

How to proceed?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask] and [mcve].  Also do some research first (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370907/should-we-still-expect-people-to-read-basic-documentation-before-asking).  This site will help to get you started: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide.  You will need the commands `mv`, `date`, a loop (`while` or `for`).  Get started, if you are stuck on a specific issue, then research and post here if all else fails.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what your requirements are, but hopefully this is enough to get you started.

Bash will expand a glob to a list of names, so you can iterate over that directly. `*` for all files in the current directory, `test.log.*` is probably more specific to your files.

`date` will print out the current date, and you can capture the output of a command in bash using `$(...)`.

```
for f in test.log.*; do
    mv "$f" "$f.$(date -I)"
done
```

It's useful when writing loops like this to stick `echo` in front of the commands so that it prints them out instead of running them and you can confirm that it's going to do what you expect it to do before you run it for real.

Run this and see if the commands are what you expect:

```
for f in test.log.*; do echo mv "$f" "$f.$(date -I)"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble understanding your requirement. What will be the output format? Hope, below command will help you in appending the date to the end of the file.

**Initial file name**

[image]

```
rename "s/$/$(date +%Y%m%d)/" *
```

**Updated file name**

[image]

"rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.
Here I have mentioned $ as first argument since we need to append to the last. (^ is for first character)